# Multiple Meteor.wrapAsync functions at once

Tags: meteor

I have a function that is wrapped with Meteor.wrapAsync().

I do a _.each loop on an array and for each item, I do this Meteor.wrapAsync(MY_FUNCTION) function. However because the function is async, it stops before each loop item.

Instead of doing one by one, how can I perform all of these async functions at once and wait until ALL of them are finished?

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940806/meteor-synchronizing-multiple-async-queries-before-returning/25941287#25941287 ?

Comment: Can we see some code please?