# How can I run asynchronous calls in batches in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, meteor

I am trying to make multiple API calls asynchronously in Meteor.  I want to run some functions at the same time, and then when they are done, be able to use all those results to do something else.  Below outlines what I mean:

```
Http.get(something)
Http.get(something else)
Http.get(something more)
Http.get(something even else more)
```

I want to be able to run these at the same time, and then when they are done, access the data all at once.  What is the best way to do something like this in Meteor?

Comment: Is this running on the client or the server?

Comment: May be a duplicate of a previous question, see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940806/meteor-synchronizing-multiple-async-queries-before-returning/25941287#25941287

Comment: @DavidWeldon.  It is running on the server

Comment: thanks @saimeunt, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Someone commented on your answer that wrapAsync can help replace that.  Is that possible.  If so, how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to do stuff in `Meteor.methods`

For your case use, you can use `http` package in meteor.

Use of `http` package is two-fold- it can act as synchronous or async, depending on how you use it.

First of all add package to your project using `meteor add http`

then.
if you are using as

```
result = Meteor.http.get("http://headers.jsontest.com/")
console.log('output of http.get here ' + result)
```

and not passing second parameter to `http.get` as "async callback function", it behaves as the **synchronous call**, that is output of `get` will be in `result` variable

and you are passing second parameter like this

```
  result = Meteor.http.get("http://ip.jsontest.com/", function(err, res){
    console.log('output of http.get here ' + JSON.stringify(res))
  })
```

It will behave as the **asynchronous call**, that is result of `http.get` will be in `res` inside callback  and not in `result` variable

In your case, use first one like

```
  result2 = Meteor.http.get("http://headers.jsontest.com/")
  result3 = Meteor.http.get("http://date.jsontest.com/")
  console.log("result 2 here " + result2)
  console.log("result 3 here "+ result3)
```

Now, with `result2` and `result3` you can do anything you want

For your reference i created example in meteorpad- check it out -http://meteorpad.com/pad/E8w3xRFor9rfX7YMX/sample-stackoverflow-example

Check out the `someMethod` inside `common.js` file

You can call this method from client side with - `Meteor.call('someMethod')` and check output on server console

You will need to access above app from here- http://app-tedmqdye.meteorpad.com/
Which you can get it from right-pane

Comment: The meteorpad didn't work for me. When I type `Meteor.call('someMethod')` from the browser console, I get an error, `Error invoking Method 'someMethod': Method not found [404]`

Comment: @LarryMaccherone you might need to use from app url and not meteor pad url- Here is url- http://app-tedmqdye.meteorpad.com/

Comment: You can not do this from the client, unfortunately. The Meteor docs state that the callback is required from the client. You need to sync wrap it on the client to achieve this result. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: @ajduke, Thanks. I have never used meteorpad before. I think I will start using it more often. Just clicking on even the latest link doesn't work all by itself, you have to click on the first link and have that up and running and then do the call from the second link. Makes sense once you understand the paradigm of how it's running. Again, thanks.

Comment: @krose ok, You might be right for client side, but i mentioned in post that i am assuming OP wants to this multiples calls from server side (which can be obvious that heavy processing will be done on server side like this one ) and specifically from `Meteor.methods`

Comment: @ajduke Not sure why that's so obvious. I was doing something very similar client-side for testing purposes . The OP didn't mention client or server, so I gave an answer that works on both, and referenced yours for a simpler way of doing it server-side.

Answer (score -1):

As far as getting those to run in parallel and detecting when the last returns, I have no idea. If you don't mind running them serially, those Http.gets follow the node callback style, so you should be able to use a wrapAsync() function to convert it to be psuedo-synchronous, meaning you would get the result of the callback as a return value from each call (although they will be using Futures so they don't block). You can check out [Meteor.wrapAsync](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) or Arunoda's [async](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/async) package for methods that convert async methods to sync (I'm oversimplifying that, but it has the same effect). Here's an example of what you could do:

```
syncGet = Meteor.wrapAsync(Http.get)

res1 = syncGet(url1, options1)
res2 = syncGet(url2, options2)
res3 = syncGet(url3, options3)
res4 = syncGet(url4, options4)

// Do something with the above results here
```

Here's a great read on sync and async functions in Meteor, if you're not already familiar:
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/

Short of that, you could also nest each call within the callback of the previous, which would look pretty gross, and still have the effect of running serially.

Note: If you are running this strictly from the server, see Adjuke's answer, which will be a bit simpler in that case.

Comment: The down vote was because your answer ignores the question about asynchronous calls and answers something else.  You acknowledge this in your first line with 'I have no idea' which is great but it is still showing up as the top answer and might lead someone astray.

Comment: @user728291 The only other answer does the exact same thing. Why not downvote them too while you're at it? My answer still very much addresses a major part of the question, which is waiting for the results to come back. I assumed that he wanted the calls to be asynchronous so that they wouldn't block the event loop. Well, when you use Meteor.wrapAsync, the code is still run asynchronously! It just uses a Future to get the callback return placed back on the event loop later. Meaning no blocking, while the code still runs "asynchronously"...

Comment: ...The code simply _looks_ synchronous. I certainly was not ignoring the question about asynchronous calls. It's not like the OP was insanely specific about what they were trying to achieve. I gave an answer that would certainly be suitable for some individuals in the predicament he described.